# How to save the data from an ajax query and pass it as a parameter in another function?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have this function:

```
function getValues(name) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "file_name.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            'product': name,
            'query': 'get_values'
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){ 



        }
    });  
}
```

and i would like to extract the data and use them as a parameter in another function. How is it possible with JQuery?

Comment: Please elaborate on what data do you need, is it the data returned by the `success` function ? And what is the other function you want to pass it to ? Also explain the need to do this using jQuery.

Comment: The data is options deriving from the success function:<option>data1</option>
<option>data2</option>
<option>data3</option>
and in the other function creates a dropdown and i want to put those options inside the <select>

Comment: Derived how ? And please also answer my other two questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```
var responseData;
function getValues(name) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "file_name.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      'product': name,
      'query': 'get_values'
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){ 
      responseData = data;
    }
  });  
}


function getValues2(){
  //Here you can use the data from first ajax call
 console.log(responseData);
}
```

I've used a variable which can be accessable by both the method.

Another method by passing as parameter

```
function getValues(name) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "file_name.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      'product': name,
      'query': 'get_values'
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){ 
      getValues2(data);
    }
  });  
}


function getValues2(data){
  //Here you can use the data from first ajax call
  console.log(data);
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The problem is that the other function (getValues2) takes also other paramaters apart from data, which are defined inside the function

Comment: So then pass them along with it with the `getValues2(data)` function like `getValues2(data, foo, bar)`

Comment: Yes you are right, but the foo and bar parameters are defined inside the function. So, they are considered as undefined in the first function

Comment: @A.Developer Please create a `jsfiddle` with the similar code as you are mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
//define var outside function.
var myData;

function getValues(name) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "file_name.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      'product': name,
      'query': 'get_values'
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
     //save data to variable
     myData = data;
    }
  });
}
```

Then you can use it...

```
function foo() {
 //do something with
 myData;
}
```

or do this in your ajax

```
success: function(data) {
 fooBar(data);
}

function fooBar(data) {
 //do something...
}
```

Comment: In what way? Have you debugged it? You can't be as vague as 'does not work'.

Comment: It is said that myData is undefined

Comment: For which method.. I put two. You **must** define the variable outside of any function **first** then you will be able to access it inside your ajax function.

Comment: I found another way.I have another question. How would it be possible to pass another argument called index from getValues(name, index) inside ajax success?

Comment: You do it in exactly how you just wrote it.

Comment: Where is the parameter `index` coming from originally? It doesn't exist within `getValues()` or the ajax function within that.

Comment: I want to insert it in getValues and then inside success to use it like this:  success: function(data){
    
 var item = $('<span>\
                            <select class="class1" id="' + index + '" name="name1" >' + data + '</select>\
           $('.dropdown').append(item);
  
    }

Comment: But where is `index` coming from? It actually has to **exist** before you can use it. Can you `console.log(index);` **outside** of `getValues()` ?

Comment: It is defined. I have already checked it.  The problem is inside ajax success.

Comment: You want to pass custom data into the success function. It shows you an example of exactly that.

Comment: I see your point and you are absolutely right. However, it seems to be difficult to implement it in my case: Here is what i tried without any success:

Comment: I would recommend opening this as a new question if you're still stuck. This is drifting off topic

Comment: function getValues(name, index) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "example.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                'product': name,
                'query': 'get_values',
  'index': index 
            },
            dataType: "html",
   success: function(data){
    var item = $('<select class="class1" id="' + this.data.index + '" name="name1" >' + data + '</select>\
                                        <label>Product name</label>');
           $('.dropdown').append(item);
   }});}

Comment: I already did it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422205/how-to-pass-a-parameter-inside-ajax-success

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Good practice is to make another http call in complete status.
Try this

```
var dataToPost="";

$.ajax({ 
 url: "file_name.php",
 type: "GET", 
 data: { 'product': name, 'query': 'get_values' },
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data){
  dataToPost = data; 
   }, 
  complete:function(){
     var a=dataToPost; 
     $.ajax({ 
     type: "post",
      url: "example.php", 
     data: 'page='+a, 
     success: function(data){
       /*do some thing in second function*/
      } }, 
});
```